# same nav html section in all files?

Tags: html, nav

I'm a complete beginner in web design. I couldn't find an answer after some search.
I purchased a template to create my personal website, and now I'm editing the navigation bar data. Yet, it seems that I have to copy and paste this in every single html file that has the navigation bar, which doesn't seem right.
Is there a way to have all this data in a single file, and then edit it once so that it's automatically included in all pages?
Thank you.
aa

Comment: possible duplicate of [best practice to create a template in html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16132341/best-practice-to-create-a-template-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

Just include nav.html where you want it to be(inside your code):

```
 include('nav.html');
```

You main code must be in index.html.Put the code for nav in nav.html and then include nav.html in index.html where you want your nav to be.

Comment: Thanks Dchris for your answer. Does this file has to only contain the code between <nav>?

Comment: Yes but pay attention to include your nav between the right <div></div>

Comment: I can't do it, and I don't know what's wrong. The code I have is as follows:

    `<body class="test">

  <!-- Header Wrapper -->
   <div id="header-wrapper">
    <div class="5grid-layout">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="12u">
      
       <!-- Header -->
        <header id="header">
         
         <!-- Logo -->
          <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" width="245" height="35" alt=""></a>
         
         <!-- Nav -->
          <nav id="nav" class="mobileUI-site-nav">`

and I even tried to put all that into the nav.html but it doesn't work. What's wrong?

Comment: I don't know what I am doing wrong, but I just can't get it to work. As you saw in my previous comment, the <nav> is inside all that code. I tried to put all of that code within the nav.mtml file but it doesn't work. Could you please develop on what you suggest?

Answer (score -1):

You save nav in single file, ex nav.htm , then included using iframe or java scirpt.

Iframe: `<iframe src="nav.htm"></iframe>`

Javasciprt, you can using jquery

```
 <html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script> 
    $(function{
      $("#nav").load("nav.htm"); 
    });
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <div id="nav"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @namthienmenh, I'm trying your approach but when I put the code on nav.htm the bar shows up in a different spot (and it lost its properties). Is the code you put above correct?