# How display an external html page in a webpage - using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to display an existing html page in another page.
The object> tag displays it inside an iframe - which I don't want.

I read here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148357/including-external-html-file-to-another-html-file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFBsX.jpg)

That it can be done with this piece of javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#header').load('name.html',function(){alert('loaded')});
});
</script>
```

Before this I've inserted:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But I'm getting the error:
**DOMException: failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on element**

What have I missed?

PS. I tried the document.write+="html+javascript-goes-here" method, but the external page-content is large so the document.write is long, cumbersome, and thus difficult to later understand/maintain.

[image]

Comment: No need for the ‘e’ inside the function definition. function()

Comment: Your getting that error in the console? Does it originate from the jquery library or your script?

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the error to the original question above.

Comment: Just noticed that it's also reporting: message: "$ is not defined"

Comment: I'm pretty sure you cant do this, you'll get a cross domain error if trying to call a different domain (aka, external).  This is by design so that you cant just embed other people's content into your pages.   If you DO own it, then just use SSI if your server supports it.

Comment: OK, my example is cross-domain, but my (hoped for) code will not be. it's not a x-domain I seem to be failing with.  Plus unfortunately!! my host environment (shopify) doesnt allow SSI.

Comment: You'll find all kinds of CSS style collisions. Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks stackOverflow - Got it running, once I'd spotted the  "$ is not defined"  error msg.
Surrounded my function with:

```
(function($){
.... function here ...
})(jQuery);
```

and:

```
<div id="header"></div>
```

in the body.

Comment: Could we see your `<head></head>` because I've never had to do this before and I'm wondering if you're loading a plugin before core or something causing $ to not longer represent JQuery.