# How can I link multiple html files in one (like you do with the `script` element)

Tags: html, css

My question is simple. Like how you can use

```
<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript' src='.path/to/script.js'>
</script>
```

to link scripts in an HTML file, how do you do that to display multiple html files in one? For example, have multiple `<div>` tags, one link to each external HTML file in them for organizing purposes?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you want is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148357/including-external-html-file-to-another-html-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to arheive this consider using jQuery:

You can do this by using jQuery `.load` function. You can read more about using .load [here](https://api.jquery.com/load/#:%7E:text=It%20is%20roughly%20equivalent%20to,elements%20to%20the%20returned%20data.)

There is no proper direct way to import your `.html` or `.php` files by adding them in to the `head`

**Note:** There are few libraries you can search by googling BUT remember most of them are **Deprecated** and will not work in **CHROME** and **OTHER BROWSER** like this one [here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/)

You can define the location of where your other HTML files `divs` should be loaded like i have done below.

```
<html>

<head>
  <script type='text/javascript' language='javascript' src='.path/to/script.js'>
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#loadDivs").load("file.html");
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="loadDivs"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I have never used jquery before so never would of thought of that.

Comment: @uncannyorange Its ideal to use jQuery as it will make it easy for you learn as well.

Comment: Can it load my file if I made it so it can’t be embedded in <iframe> Or <embed> Tags?

Comment: @uncannyorange You can load dynamic content your `iframe` as well using the above example in my answer. Just change the div the iframe and load file content in there. It will hard to exactly know what are you trying to load BUT you can use the method in the answer to load anything from another `.html` or `.php` file