# html block content printed as {% block content %} {% endblock %} string

Tags: html

`test.html`

```
{% extends "main.html" %}
{% block content %}
<p>block test</p>
{% endblock %}
```

I add to `main.html`

```
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
```

`main.html` and `test.html` are in the same directory.
[image]

but in the main page literally `{% block content %} {% endblock %}` are printed like this ↓.

[image]

I don't know why. I've tried `{% extends "./main.html" %}` but also doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148357/including-external-html-file-to-another-html-file

Comment: This is not standard HTML, it seems to be template for [django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/language)