# Navigation inside an iFrame: How to go to another page outside of iFrame

Tags: html, iframe

I've got a page that has navigation inside of an iFrame. When I click on the navigation links inside the iFrame, the content only loads inside it. Is there a way for me to click on the links inside the iFrame and have the whole page go somewhere else? Not just the iFrame?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this iFrame from you domain or a different on? Post some code

Comment: this iFrame is in same domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [the target attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#attr-hyperlink-target):

```
<a href="foo" target="_top">
```

Better yet, don't use frames for this. Use [some form of template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16132516/19068) instead.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help! The iFrame was left from previous guy, and the owner doesn't want to change anything. So I'm stuck with it.

Answer (score 1):

If the two pages are within the same domain you could try defining the following function into the outer frame:

```
function navigateToUrl(url){window.location = url;}
```

And then calling it from the inner frame like this:

```
if(typeof(parent.navigateToUrl)==typeof(Function)){parent.navigateToUrl('newPage.html')}
```

Comment: Wow. That's … an overly complicated approach to the problem.

Comment: So for example, the navigation is in the iFrame, but I have a link in the iFrame that goes to google. When clicked on that google link only the iFrame will navigate there. I need the whole page to go to google instead.