# I want to load the Page in the div

Tags: html

```
 <div class="div1">
             <ul class="menu">
                <li ><a id="li1" href="main.html" target="content">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a id="li2" href="catog.html" target="content">ALL CATOGREIS</a></li>
                <li><a id="li3" href="about us.html" target="content">ABOUT US</a></li>
                <li><a id="li4" href="contact us.html" target="content">CONTACT US</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <div name="content" class="content">

    </div>
```

I used target="_self" but nothing happened what should I do

Comment: You must explain your problem a little bit better so we can understand what you are trying to do, what you have tried and what the problem is...  Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: **Warning**: Writing content in all caps will cause many screen readers to think it is an initialism and spell it out letter-by-letter. If you want all caps for stylistic purposes then use [a style sheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform)

Answer (score 1):

Divs and iframes are different elements and cannot be used interchangeably.

A div is a generic element for grouping content without adding additional semantics.

An iframe is an element for embedding other documents.

[If you want an iframe, use an iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe).

(I don't recommend them as they are nasty user interfaces and bad food for search engines. Putting your navigation menu on each page is a better approach. There are [automated ways to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16132516/19068) so you don't need to maintain it yourself.)